# SQL Server (2014) Query Optimization when using filter variable passed to procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, optimization, sql-server-2014

I am looking for help with optimization techniques or hint for me to move ahead with the problem I have. Using a temp table for in clause makes my query run for more than 5 seconds, changing it a static value returns the data under a second. I am trying to understand the way to optimize this.

```
-- details about the number of rows in table
dept_activity table

    - total rows                - 17,319,666
    - rows for (dept_id = 10)   - 36054

-- temp table 
CREATE TABLE #tbl_depts (
    Id INT Identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,dept_id integer
);

-- for example I inserted one row but based on conditions multiple department numbers are inserted in this temp table
insert into #tbl_depts(dept_id) values(10);

-- this query takes more than 5 seconds
SELECT activity_type,count(1) rc
FROM dept_activity da
WHERE (
        @filter_by_dept IS NULL
        OR da.depart_id IN (
            SELECT td.dept_id
            FROM #tbl_depts td
            )
        )
group by activity_type;

-- this query takes less than 500 milli seconds
SELECT activity_type,count(1) rc
FROM dept_activity da
WHERE (
        @filter_by_dept IS NULL
        OR da.depart_id IN (
                10 -- changed to static value
            )
        )
group by activity_type;
```

What ways I can optimize to return data for first query under a second.

Comment: how about using union like this `SELECT activity_type,count(1) rc
FROM dept_activity da
WHERE         filter_by_dept IS NULL
group by activity_type
union 
SELECT activity_type,count(1) rc
FROM dept_activity da
WHERE da.depart_id IN (
            SELECT td.dept_id
            FROM #tbl_depts td
)
group by activity_type;`

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(`right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics)` and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Answer (score 0):

You're testing this with just one value, but isn't your real case different?

The problem that optimizer has here is that it can't know how many rows the temp. table in -clause will actually find, so it'll have to make a guess, and probably that why the result is different. Looking at estimated row counts (+vs actual) might give some insight on this.

If your clause only contains this one criteria:

```
@filter_by_dept IS NULL OR da.depart_id IN
```

It might be good to test what happens if you separate your logic with `if` blocks, into the one that fetches all, and the other that filters the data.

If that's not the real case, you might want to test both `option (recompile)`, which could result into a better plan, but will use (little bit) more CPU since the plan is re-generated every time. Or by constructing the clause with dynamic SQL (either just with the temp table but optimizing away the `or` statements, or doing a full `in` clause if there isn't a ridiculous amount of values), but that might get really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of writing same thing. Use as per your requirements -

**Separate Block**

```
IF @filter_by_dept IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT da.activity_type, count(1) rc
    FROM dept_activity da 
    GROUP BY da.activity_ty
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT da.activity_type,COUNT(1) rc
    FROM dept_activity da
    INNER JOIN #tbl_depts td ON td.dept_id = da.depart_id
    GROUP BY da.activity_ty
END
```

**Dynamic Query**

```
DECLARE @sql_stmt VARCHAR(5000)    
SET @sql_stmt = '
        SELECT activity_type, COUNT(1) rc
        FROM dept_activity da
    '

IF @filter_by_dept IS NOT NULL
    SET @sql_stmt = @sql_stmt + ' INNER JOIN #tbl_depts td ON td.dept_id = da.depart_id'

SET @sql_stmt = @sql_stmt + ' GROUP BY da.activity_type '
EXEC(@sql_stmt)
```

**Simple Left Join**
Comparatively, it can be slower that above two options.

```
SELECT da.activity_type, count(1) rc
FROM dept_activity da
LEFT JOIN #tbl_depts td ON td.dept_id = da.depart_id
WHERE @filter_by_dept IS NULL OR td.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY da.activity_type
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is most likely the use of an "optional parameter". The query optimizer has no idea weather or not @filter_by_dept is going to have a value the next time it's executed to it chooses to play it safe opts for an index scan, rather than an index seek. The is where OPTION(RECOMPILE) can be your friend. Especially on simple, easy to compile queries like this one.
Also, there are potential gains from using a WHERE EXISTS in place of the IN.

Try the following...

```
DECLARE @filter_by_dept INT = 10;

SELECT 
    da.activity_type,
    rc = COUNT(1)
FROM 
    dbo.dept_activity da
WHERE 
    @filter_by_dept IS NULL
    OR 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tbl_depts td WHERE da.depart_id = td.dept_id)
GROUP BY
    da.activity_type
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

HTH, Jason